# Scala: Making concrete classes of trait with type member that has a representation type

Tags: scala

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236122/) where I had a trait `Garage` with a type member `CarType`, which itself had a type member `FuelType`, and I needed a function `refuel` that could take an instance of `CarType` as the first argument and an instance of the first argument's `FuelType` as the second argument.

The answer, the two traits below, was to give `Car` a representation type `C <: Car[C]`. The problem that I now have is that I can't figure out how to define the type parameter on the concrete classes implementing `Garage`, e.g. `ConcreteGarage` below.

```
trait Fuel

trait Garage {
  type CarType <: Car[CarType]
  def cars: Seq[CarType]

  def copy(cars: Seq[CarType]): Garage

  def refuel(car: CarType, fuel: CarType#FuelType): Garage = copy(
    cars.map {
      case `car` => car.refuel(fuel)
      case other => other
    })
}

trait Car[C <: Car[C]] {
  type FuelType <: Fuel
  def fuel: FuelType

  def copy(fuel: C#FuelType): C

  def refuel(fuel: C#FuelType): C = copy(fuel)
}

class ConcreteGarage(val cars: Seq[ConcreteGarage#CarType]) extends Garage {
  type CarType = Car[CarType] // Nope
  //type CarType = Car[Any] // Nope
  //type CarType = Car[Nothing] // Nope
  //type CarType = Car[Car] // Nope
  //type CarType <: Car[CarType] // Nope
  def copy(cars: Seq[CarType]) = new ConcreteGarage(cars)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why I said beware of the ugliness of having to carry around another type parameter *for the rest of your life* :)

```
class ConcreteGarage[C <: Car[C]](val cars: Seq[C]) extends Garage {
  type CarType = C
  def copy(cars: Seq[C]) = new ConcreteGarage(cars)
}
```

Of course, its simpler if you have a *particular* garage.

```
case class Benzin(litres: Int) extends Fuel
case class Mustang(fuel: Benzin) extends Car[Mustang] {
   type FuelType = Benzin
   def copy(fuel: Benzin) = Mustang(fuel)
}
case class MustangGarage(cars: Seq[Mustang]) extends Garage {
   type CarType = Mustang
   def copy(cars: Seq[Mustang]) = MustangGarage(cars)
}

val m = Mustang(Benzin(0))
val g0 = MustangGarage(Seq(m))
val g1 = g0.refuel(m, Benzin(45))
```

Comment: What do you mean? The 'boilerplate' in the general case is the qualification `[C <: Car[C]]` -- you need to chose: Either you want 'easier' types, then relax the constraints and allow any car to be used with any type of fuel; you can even drop type parameters altogether; or you want strong type constraints, then you'll have a minimum of effort to state those constraints.

Comment: The general qualifications `[C <: Car[C]]` for representation types eventually need to qualify every trait that uses them, which then need to qualify every trait that uses *them*. Your rewrite of this problem using existential types in the [follow-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277656/) to this question seems to provide a better long-term solution to these kinds of structures.

Comment: Exactly; you need to carry around at least one such type, whether that's `Car` or `World`. If the number of type parameters grows, it can be the less bitter medicine to stick with the world approach.